# AngularJS $add() function not firing

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that is being populated with information from a table.  When I the record has a role or multiple roles it displays as expected however I cannot add additional roles, and I cannot add any roles to the record if there was none.    Something is wrong with my $add() function.

Another issue is the password and confirm password are displaying the same data. I am trying to figure this out right now as well.

```
<form ng-model="current">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                    <a href="" alt="Register" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" ng-click="newItem()"><i
                            class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> New </a>
                    Detail
                </legend>
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="current.firstName" value="current.firstName"
                       ng-disabled="isKey('lastName')">

                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="current.lastName" value="current.lastName"
                       ng-disabled="isKey('firstName')">

                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="user@example.com" ng-model="current.email" value="current.email"
                       ng-disabled="isKey('email')">

                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="current.password" value="current.Pass"
                       ng-disabled="isKey('Pass')">

                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="current.password" value="current.Pass"
                       ng-disabled="isKey('Pass')">

                <label>Enabled</label>
                <select ng-model="current.enabled" ng-disabled="isKey('enabled')">
                    <option value=true>Enabled</option>
                    <option value=false>Disabled</option>
                </select>

                <div class="role" ng-repeat="role in current.roles">
                    <label>User Roles</label>
                    <select ng-model="role.roleName" ng-disabled="isKey('role')">
                        <option value="ROLE_USER">User</option>
                        <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">Administrator</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <label></label>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" ng:click="current.role.$add()">Add Role</a>
                <label></label>
                <a href="#askCreateUser" alt="Register" role="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                   ng-click="setDataOperation('Update')"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Update </a>
                <a href="#askCreateUser" alt="Register" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"
                   ng-click="setDataOperation('Delete')"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete </a>
            </fieldset>

        </form>
```

Comment: Your password and confirm password will be displaying the same as they are using the same `ng-model`. Regarding your `$add` function, you really need to provide a plnkr or jsfiddle example so that others can help you.

Comment: You should attach your controller code so we may see what's this form connected to, and what you `current.role.$add` function looks like. Beside that, you are not using angular models (and form) the way they  are supposed to be used. You're not ought to use value attribute when your inputs are connected to the model through ng-model directive. You might want to learn more about [Angular form directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and [ng-model](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this was due to trying to push to an empty array. After adding the below function I was able to add elements without issue.

```
 $scope.addRole = function () {
        if ($scope.current.roles != undefined) {
            $scope.current.roles.push({});
        }
        else {
            $scope.current.roles = new Array();
            $scope.current.roles.push({});
        }
    };
```